# Firebase - Retention Rates(Cohort)

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, retention

I have a question on the way Firebase calculates retention rates.

At my company, we release a new version almost every 2-3 weeks, and a lot of people uninstall the app to get the latest version.

If an active user uninstalls and reinstalls the app to access new features, would that user be counted as an inactive user, and the user would be included in the new cohort?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when users reinstall your app they are regarded as a brand new user, they get new instance id/[user_pseudo_id](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?hl=en) assigned. Which in your case means you will have worse retention rate that you actually have. But if you have any way of identifying users (which you can probably do using [Advertising ID](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6048248?hl=en-GB)) you could override this instance id with your own [userID](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/userid).